# NSTimer seems to be invalidated when I use a popOver

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an NSTimer displaying text over time.  If a popOver shows up at the same time, the timer seems to just die.  The method it's calling stops printing log statements, and my code is definitely never invalidating it.

Is this expected behavior? Should I never have a popOver when I'm running a timer?

Edit:  By "at the same time" I mean, before the NSTimer has been invalidated by me (it's still displaying text), a user triggers a popOver, which prevents the NSTimer from continuing.  I have methods surrounding invaliding a NSTimer which print log statements, and am invalidating it nowhere but that method.  The log statements aren't displaying when a popOver happens.

Here's how I'm calling the popOver:

```
if ([self.popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {
    SubMenuViewController *popup = [[SubMenuViewController alloc] initWithStorySections:tmp_menu];

    self.popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popup];
    popup.delegate = self;
    [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.textView.frame inView: self.backgroundView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

I don't THINK I'm doing any weird threading things with it, but it still interferes with my timer.  I do notice that that the timer is already called before the popup is triggered, could that be doing anything?

Comment: Is there anything in your `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` methods ?

Comment: please, show your code… what do you mean by "at the same time"? where is the timer created?

Comment: Nope, my viewWillAppear and Disappear are both empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timer shouldn't be killed by a popover, but it does depend on the popover.  If you have a custom made one that's not calling the main runloop, that might be your problem.  You want to make sure the system gets time so it can call your timer call.  Otherwise, put breakpoints on all your calls to invalidate the timer and see if one is getting called on you.

Comment: I have a method that invalidates the timer and it prints a log statement.  Nowhere else in my code invalidates the timer, and my log statement is never being called.  My popover is the standard one, that has a custom UIViewController inside it... I'll post how I'm calling the popover.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the timer was the problem, but apparently I just missed the log statement.